# Positive Definiteness problem

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Consider the positive definite matrix $B \succ 0$ and the matrix ( not necessarily square) $A$. what can we say abut the positive definiteness of:
$$ A^\prime B A$$
My hunch is that this is positive semi definite due to the lack of constraints on $A$ meaning there is a vector $x \neq 0$ such that $Ax=0$.
\begin{align}
x^\prime A^\prime B A x &=(Ax)^\prime B(Ax) \\
&\rightarrow trace(B||Ax||^2) \ge 0
\end{align}
the eigenvalues of this are greater than or equal to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, but there is an easier way to see it. Why not denote $Ax$ as $y$ so  you don't know $y$ equals 0 or not, but you can always have $y'Ay\geq 0$.

Comment: That's great thank you. I was pretty sure but just needed the second opinion!